# How to call an API Gateway API once a week

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a REST API built using API Gateway with a couple of methods.  I need to run a `POST` request on a method `/generate-stats` once a week.  I currently call this method through the AWS console by pasting a request body into the "Test" feature that exists in API Gateway under the Method Execution flowchart.

How would I go about automating this call?  Would a lambda that runs once a week be the simplest solution?  Ideally I can store the response or trigger an alarm if the request fails.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html - you can create a really small lambda that calls the api gateway, stores the result or just logs it and if you monitor that lambda invocation properly you would get notified of invocation errors.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to automate a request to happen once a week you would want to look at using [Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/).

The service itself supports either being triggered by an event (such as a new PutObject into S3 or an instance being launched) or can run based on a schedule. You would want to use the latter to set a cron expression for running this.

The next part of the rule is the target which in this case are a couple of approaches.

[API Gateway requests are a supported target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/targets-apigateway.html) from within the event. If the supported functionality with EventBridge is suitable for you then you will be able to perform the request directly without any additional services.

If additional functionality is required you would need to create a Lambda function that could perform the request to API Gateway. This Lambda would then be the trigger for the event leading to the same functionality being performed.

Comment: I ended up using EventBridge with a schedule, this was basically exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a Lambda function that can use code to perform a POST request. Then you can use scheduled events to schedule when the Lambda function will be invoked. Using a CRON expression, you can schedule your Lambda to fire once a week. For details, see:

[Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)